# Laravel adding image to email template

Tags: php, laravel, email

i am new to laravel and i need to add logo to my email. I tried almost everything i saw as solution, first image was showing as a broken img, now i cannot send mail at all.

this is my controller:

```
public static function sendRefferanceMail($student_id, $reference_id)
{
    $reference = Reference::find($reference_id);


    if ($reference->is_confirmed == 0 || $reference->is_confirmed == 1 ) {
        //Create token with student's id
        $token = Helper::generateToken($reference_id);
        $is_token = Reference::where('token', $token)->count();
        while ($is_token > 0) {
            $token = Helper::generateToken($reference_id);
            $is_token = Reference::where('token', $token)->count();
        }
        $array = [
            'student_name' => $reference->getStudent->name,
            'student_surname' => $reference->getStudent->surname,
            'name' => $reference->referencer_name,
            'email' => $reference->referencer_email,
            'token' => $token,
            'referencer_id' => $reference->id,
            'student_id' => $student_id,
];
        Mail::send('/mailtemplates/refferance', $array, function ($message) use ($reference) {
            $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'Info');
            $message->subject("Referance");
            $message->to($reference->referencer_email);
        });
```

and in my view i am trying to use as

```
<tr>
                    <td class="wrapper">
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path() . 'front/assets/images/logo.png') }}" alt="" ">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Hello {{$name}},</p>
                                    <p>Your appeal is approved.</p>
                                    <p><br></p>
                                    <p>Fırat University</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

any help how to solve this?

Comment: try  <img src="{{ public_path()}}front/assets/images/logo.png" alt="" >

Comment: you just need $message->embed('app/front/assets/img/home/partner-business/texas.png'); not want to added public_path()

Comment: or just pass $message->embed('upload/frontside/0241589d3a608d67cc26e87968fd6eb6_pam_rehabiliation_logo.png');